# Saving canvas element

Tags: javascript, download, html5-canvas

I found that I could download the contents of a `<canvas>` element to file, by using the following script:

```
var download = function(){

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = 'filename.png';
    link.href = cvs2.toDataURL();
    link.click();
}
```

When using this method on Chrome (android) however, it seems to have downloaded the file into a private chrome folder on my device. What I need is for the canvas contents to be downloaded as an image file into the normal download folder(ie `/sdcard/Downloads`).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [the `toBlob()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) on the `canvas` element to first acquire a file/blob of the canvas contents. Then, use the `createObjectURL()` and `revokeObjectURL()` methods of the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) as shown, to get and assign the corresponding `url` to your temporary download link:

```
var download = function(filename, mimeType) {

  /* Use toBlob to get a file from the canvas element */
  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {

    /* Get url for this file blob */
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    /* Create temporary link and start download */
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = url;
    link.click();

    /* Clean up */
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

  }, mimeType);
}

/* Usage example */
download('my-filename.png', 'image/png')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this cross-browser?

Comment: Hi @ProJser - the `toBlob` method is widely supported (except for Edge desktop/mobile as far as I'm aware). The `URL` API methods used in the answer are pretty much available across the board (except for older pre 10 versions of IE). Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

For chrome you can use [donwloads.download()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download)